# How many letters can bytes32 keep?

Tags: string, bytes32

I would like to add strings into bytes32. What is the maximum number of letters bytes32 can have?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each `bytes32` can store up to 32 letters (ASCII): each character is a byte.

Comment: How about UTF-8?

Comment: Same answer 32: the first 128 characters of UTF-8 correspond one-to-one with ASCII, which is where the usual letters and numbers are.